# How do i export and import a large collection(more than 5000 data) in cloud Firestore database with nodejs and firestore-export-import npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

How do i export a large collection(more than 5000 data) in Firestore with nodejs and firestore-export-import npm?

But I getting an error on

> (node:9592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE:
>   The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily
>   unavailable.
>       at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
>       at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:328:49)
>       at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:304:181)
>       at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:115:74)
>       at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:154:22)
>       at Http2CallStream.endCall (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:140:18)
>       at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:265:14)
>       at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at emit (internal/http2/core.js:245:8)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17) (node:9592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:9592) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

how to resolved this error

Comment: When you say 5000 data do you mean documents ? Collections ? 5000 MB ? Could you please provide more details to understand exactly how to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @Waelmas Data is more than 25000 documents and 5000 collection. I googled and found that it was a query timeout but I am not sure what it is. Thanks in advance